# How to implement if Registry does not exists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

In my Rails App, I have a line that says:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && Registry.exists?(current_user.registry) %>
```

How can I make it

```
if Registry. **does not** exists?(current_user.registry)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if user_signed_in? && !Registry.exists?(current_user.registry)
```

(note the exclamation mark) or

```
if user_signed_in? and not Registry.exists?(current_user.registry)
```

if you like that better for its readability. As well in Ruby, you can use `unless`, which is the same as `if not`, but might eventually be more difficult to read.

Comment: The unless statement is one of the things wich seperate ruby on rails from other platforms, so I would suggest using these. as for statements there are several options. to suggest either presence or absence of a value. take the time to figure them out since the surely come to hand